# add columns to existing file

Tags: xcode, powershell, active-directory

i imported from file IDs and base on this ID i am trying to get information from AD...and insert this information as columns in original file...this is the code:

```
$import = Import-Csv C:\Temp\coputerstatus.csv
Foreach ($item in $import) {
$user = Get-ADUSer -Identity $item.ID
#$item = New-Object psobject
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "office" -Value $user.office
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "title" -Value $user.title
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "displayname" -Value $user.name
} #foreach
$import | Export-Csv C:\temp\my.csv
```

but it is no working very well..i success to insert the headers but the value is empty(,,,)

i would like to same help

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get-ADUser and other active directory cmdlets operate a little funny.  When you ask for an ADUser object Get-ADuser only returns a small subset of the properties available.  Office and title are not available in this default set.  To get what you want add the -Property parameter to Get-ADUser and ask for title and office in addition to the defaults it normally returns

```
$user = Get-ADUSer -Identity $item.ID -Property Title, Office
```

if you want to retrieve all possible properties use an asterisk

```
$user = Get-ADUSer -Identity $item.ID -Property *
```

Answer (score 1):

It actually sounds like you may not be getting any user object back from Get-ADUser.  Have a look at what is in the ID column in your csv files.  Manually check what you are getting back from the import-csv command

```
$import = Import-Csv C:\Temp\coputerstatus.csv
$import | gm
```

Make sure that you have an ID property in that list.  If so go ahead and check if your objects have ID values that you expect

```
$import.ID
```

If everything looks fine there try taking one of those IDs and manually running the Get-ADuser command replacing $item.ID with one of the actual IDs.

```
Get-ADUSer -Identity TESTID -Property Title, Office
```

Do you get anything back?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways...you can use splatting to dump all of the properties into the CSV for each like this...

```
$import = Import-Csv C:\Temp\coputerstatus.csv
$myUsers = @()
Foreach ($item in $import) {
    $user = Get-ADUSer -Identity $item.ID -Properties *
    [pscustomobject]$MyItem = @{
        "userProps" = $user
    }
    $myUsers += $MyItem.Values
} #foreach
$myUsers | Export-Csv 'C:\temp\my.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Or you can select specific properties that you care about, like this...

```
$import = Import-Csv C:\Temp\coputerstatus.csv
$myUsers = @()
Foreach ($item in $import) {
    $user = Get-ADUSer -Identity $item.ID -Properties *
    [pscustomobject]$MyItem = @{
        "DisplayName" = $user.Name
        "Office" = $user.office
        "Title" = $user.title
    }
    $myUsers += $MyItem.Values
} #foreach
$myUsers | Export-Csv 'C:\temp\my.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```